# Tell the difference between three months

Tags: excel, date, if-statement, formula

I can't use a pivot table for this purpose, because this calculation takes place in a huge nested if formula.

Column A has unit
Column B has start date
Column C has end date
Column D:F has data.
Column E... is an attempt to bridge that data, so I can compare July to August.

EDITING QUESTION: I might as well throw it out here since everyone's doing it from scratch.

Okay, in this first picture, there's two dates, a start measurement, and a end measurement.  I take end - start.  Easy enough.

But then there's exceptions.  Sometimes D:F

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zEJl.png

But my data isn't consistent.  D:F may be full of zeroes.  Sometimes July data is in August, but according to the bridge, that's not the case.  I don't think July data will be past August 1st.

To explain that, this new picture is here.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpq7R.png

This is my current formula that I'm trying to figure out.

=IF(AND(B2>=DATE(2013,7,1),B2<=DATE(2013,8,1)),IF(G2<>0,IF(-need.to.prevent.duplicates.here-,F2-D2,0),V2),IF(AND(C2>=DATE(2013,7,1),C2<=DATE(2013,7,31)),IF(B2=DATE(2013,8,1),F2-E2,F2-D2),0))

Comment: Could you perhaps post a picture of your sheet and one calculation done by hand (without formula, one expected result)?

Comment: I'll try to have that shortly.  Working on it.

Comment: Great! You probably won't be able to post it as a picture per se, but you can still put a link to the picture in your question.

Comment: Okay, just a question, are the values in column G given?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry.  No, G is a formula where F2-D2 no matter what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found my solution.  My end result is this.

=IF(AND(B2>=DATE(2013,7,1),B2<=DATE(2013,8,1)),IF(G2<>0,IF(E2<>"",E2-D2,IF(P2=G2,0,F2-D2)),V2),IF(AND(C2>=DATE(2013,7,1),C2<=DATE(2013,7,31)),IF(N2>G2,V2-N2,G2-N2),0))

What I did was compare August to G2 (the total) to eliminate the duplicates.  If August completely resembled it, then the formula would turn July to 0.

I'm also worked a little bit on the June data side.

Answer (score 1):

Using the provided picture, try this formula in cell I32 (because that's where January should begin) and copied over and down:

```
=IF(TEXT($B32,"mmmm")=I$31,IF(TEXT($C32,"mmmm")=I$31,$G32,$E32-$D32),IF(TEXT($C32,"mmmm")=I$31,$F32-$E32,0))
```

Alternate (shortened) version to write the same thing:

```
=(TEXT($B32,"mmmm")=I$31)*($E32-$D32)+(TEXT($C32,"mmmm")=I$31)*($F32-$E32)
```

[EDIT]: I am including an example workbook [here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0Bz-nM5djZBWYVFRaeHR5NExZYWc/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Well, I've added it in column I.  It outputs all 0s.  What is it?

Comment: Did you copy it over and down? According to the picture you posted, column I should be the January column, which is why the formula starts there.  When copied over, it check's the column's header against the dates in columns B and C and then returns the appropriate value.  So when you copy it over, it should return results identical to those shown in your picture.

Comment: Oh.  Those columns aren't actually January and forth on, but I see how you came up with that.  I've only copied it down, but now I've tried across and down.  It's still all 0s.

Comment: If your data starts on row 32, you will need to adjust the row numbers that the formula is looking at, I will update the formula to match the row numbers used in the image

Comment: I have edited my answer to include a sample workbook.  The highlighted numbers show the returned results.  The July/August results for Unit 1 are identical to what is displayed in your image. Are those not the results you are expecting?

Comment: I got why it wasn't working for me.  I used a different name on the month column.  Instead of July, I had July miles.

Answer (score 0):

You have not mentioned what you would like if the months are not both August, so in the following formula (in Row1 and copied down to suit) that scenario results in FALSE:

```
=IF(AND(MONTH(B1)=8,MONTH(C1)=8),IF(ISBLANK(E1),"OTHER",E1))
```

However when both are August this should meet your requirements, subject to "OTHER" being a place holder for you alternative formula.

Edit:

I think the above meets *"I'd like a formula where if B and C has August. If so, please look for data in E. If data is not in E, do another formula."* but if you want to test the presence of E data across all instances of a 'unit` then this:

```
=IF(AND(MONTH(B6)=8,MONTH(C6)=8),IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,A6,E:E,"<>"&""),"OTHER",E6))
```

Comment: This goes for one row.  The unit has several rows and one of those rows may or may not have E data.  I need a formula that looks for E in other rows, but for that unit.

Comment: I used your formula into my formula, changed AND to OR and changed the last E6 to 0, and somehow it outputs FALSE.  I'm still trying to figure out why.